# Printing exceptions in Python, instead of raising them

Tags: python, exception

I want to catch a Python exception and print it rather than re-raising it.  For example:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return 1/x
    except:
        print <exception_that_was_raised>
```

This should then do:

```
>>> f(0)
'ZeroDivisionError'
```

without an exception being raised.

Is there a way to do this, other than listing each possible exception in a giant try-except-except...except clause?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use the `message` attribute of exception or `e.__class__.__name__` if you want the name of the Base exception class , i.e `ZeroDivisionError'` in your case

```
In [30]: def f(x):
        try:
                return 1/x
        except Exception as e:
            print e.message
   ....:         

In [31]: f(2)
Out[31]: 0

In [32]: f(0)
integer division or modulo by zero
```

In python 3.x the `message` attribute has been removed so you can simply use `print(e)` or `e.args[0]` there, and `e.__class__.__name__` remains same.

Comment: Or if you just want the exception's name:  `print e.__class__.__name__`

Comment: @mgilson's comment is really what the OP asked for; `print repr(e)` would also work.

Comment: Good, but this won't work if you raise an instance of `class Whoa: pass`

Comment: @alex_jordan -- If you raise things which aren't Exceptions, you deserve what you get I think ... quickly looking over the documentation, I'm not even positive that behaviour is well defined.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I think `repr(e)` returns kind of combination of `e.__class__.__name__` and `e.args`, i.e output is `ZeroDivisionError('integer division or modulo by zero',)
`

Answer (score 3):

This is how I work:

```
try:
    0/0
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
    0/0
except ZeroDivisionError,e:
    print e
#will print "integer division or modulo by zero"
```

Something like this,
Pythonic duck typing lets us to convert error instances into strings on the fly=)
Good luck =)